# Bootstrap Carousel Not Sliding Until Mouseover or Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Carousel Not Sliding Until Mouseover or Click: I've been working on this issue for sometime now and have yet to find a solution. I understand this potentially is a duplicate question, but I really need to find a solution for this as soon as possible and all the suggestions to date have not solved the problem. The behavior for this problem can be viewed at http://aagreen.dev.activemls.com

We have JSON data at /property/slideshow_json and the output is as follows:

```
[{"price": "105,000", "mls_number": "5013724", "address": "120 Merry, BOWLING GREEN 43402"}, {"price": "118,900", "mls_number": "5048488", "address": "612 Gypsy Lane, BOWLING GREEN 43402"}]
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     </ol>

     <!-- Carousel items -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">
     </div>

     <!-- Carousel nav -->
     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

The current version of the javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.getJSON("/property/slideshow_json", function(data){
          console.log(data);
     }).success(function(data){
          console.log("success");
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
               $(".carousel-indicators").append($( '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +index+ '"</li>' ));
               $(".carousel-inner").append($('<div class="item"><img src="/property/photo/'+value.mls_number+'/1"><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>PRICED TO SELL | $'+value.price+'</h4><p style="text-transform:uppercase;">'+value.address+' <a href="/property/detail/'+value.mls_number+'"class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right">View Details</a></p></div></div>'));
           });    
     });
     $('.carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
     $('.carousel-inner div:first').addClass('active');
     $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 4000});
});
```

Comment: I really really need help on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carousel does not start, because you call `$.carousel` before appending data.

You should start it inside `$.getJSON` success callback, like:

```
 $.getJSON("/property/slideshow_json", function(data){}).success(function(data){
      console.log("success");
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
           $(".carousel-indicators").append($( '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +index+ '"</li>' ));
           $(".carousel-inner").append($('<div class="item"><img src="/property/photo/'+value.mls_number+'/1"><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>PRICED TO SELL | $'+value.price+'</h4><p style="text-transform:uppercase;">'+value.address+' <a href="/property/detail/'+value.mls_number+'"class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right">View Details</a></p></div></div>'));

           $('.carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
           $('.carousel-inner div:first').addClass('active');
           $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 4000});               

      });    
 });
```

Comment: that worked finally! thank you for explaining to me!